# Single Channel 10 bit images

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

Is there any way in OpenGL to load and read a 10 bit image? It doesn't have to be optimal efficiency on the GPU side. I just want to offload my CPU from converting everyting to 8bit before shuffling it to the GPU.

I noticed that the only 10 bit texture format supported is RGB10, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Vendor specific extensions are alright.

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to know that this is correct/would work but couldn't you use a 16 bit texture and then only use the 10 least significant bits in the shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to offload my CPU from converting everyting to 8bit before shuffling it to the GPU.

Well, that's not going to happen. The GPU *never* does format conversions (except maybe swizzling, but that's really part of the DMA). The CPU does format conversions, which is why it is so important to avoid format mismatches.

So even if OpenGL had a way to describe 10-bit single-channel data, you'd still be relying on the CPU to decode it into the format the GPU actually uses (ie: 8-bit). It just wouldn't be *your* code doing the conversion; it'd be driver code. Either way, it's eating CPU resources.

But that's irrelevant to your needs, since OpenGL does not have a way to upload 10-bit single-channel data. How do you even store that; the pixels aren't byte-aligned.

In general, you are advised to do this kind of conversion off-line where possible and store the data in the formats where it makes the most sense.

Comment: How are the rgb10, r12 etc... formats handled, does the driver convert them to 16 bit?

Comment: @ronag: What do you mean? There is no `GL_R12` format that I'm aware of. `RGB10` works by being 32-bits in size (2 bits are lost); if you want to prevent driver-side conversion, then you upload it with GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2 or GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV, and use GL_RGBA as the upload format. If your data is 10-bit, the best solution is to convert it to 16-bit and use a `GL_R16` internal format.

Comment: sry, I meant ALPHA12 not R12.

Comment: @ronag: Who says that the driver doesn't internally convert that into `GL_ALPHA16`? That's entirely allowed by the specification.